# The constructor KafkaStreams(Topology, Properties) is undefined

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static void main(String[] args) {
    

    
    final Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "streams-task");
    props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
   // props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_TIMESTAMP_EXTRACTOR_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonTimestampExtractor.class);
    props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, JSONSerde.class);
    props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, JSONSerde.class);
   // props.put(StreamsConfig.STATESTORE_CACHE_MAX_BYTES_CONFIG, 0);
    //props.put(StreamsConfig.COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 1000L);

    
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");

    final StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();


    final KStream<String, ActivityModel> activityStream = builder.stream("local.cdc.demo.activity",Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), new JSONSerde<>()));

    //final KTable<String, > users = builder.table(sourcekafkaTopic, Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), new JSONSerde<>()))
   
            KStream<String, ActivityScoreModel> scoreStream = activityStream
                    .map((key, value) -> KeyValue.pair(key.toString(),
                    new ActivityScoreModel(value.getActivity().toString(), Float.parseFloat(value.getParticipants())
                            * Float.parseFloat(value.getPrice()) * Float.parseFloat(value.getAccessibility()))));

            scoreStream.to("local.cdc.demo.activity",Produced.with(Serdes.String(), new JSONSerde<>()));

            
            
             KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), props);
                final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

                // attach shutdown handler to catch control-c
                Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread("streams-pipe-shutdown-hook") {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        streams.close();
                        latch.countDown();
                    }
                });

                try {
                    streams.start();
                    latch.await();
                } catch (final Throwable e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    System.exit(1);
                }
                System.exit(0);
            
            

        }
```

i have to pass this json array

```
{

  "activity": "Go swimming with a friend",

  "type": "social",

  "participants": 2,

  "price": 0.1,

  "link": "",

  "key": "1505028",

  "accessibility": 0.1

}
```

output should be like
calculate a field “score” which will be participants * price * accessibility.

The resulting message will be printed and also written to topic local.cdc.demo.activity.score will be as follows

```
{

  "activity": "Go swimming with a friend",

  "score”: 2

}
```

Comment: 1) `2 * 0.1 * 0.1` does not equal a score of `2`. 2) Regarding the title of the post, that constructor does exist - https://kafka.apache.org/31/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/KafkaStreams.html 3) Your output topic does not end with `.score` like you wanted

Comment: @OneCricketeer i understood what you told but while running the program its showing me this with same program code.
 1)The constructor KafkaStreams(Topology, Properties) is undefined

Comment: Which version of the Kafka Streams dependency are you using? If you look at the Javadoc for that version, what do you see? And are you importing `java.util.Properties` and not something else? Or did you try passing `new StreamsConfig(props)`